# separating a string into different lists using tcl/tk

Tags: regex, list, split, tcl, tk-toolkit

Is it possible to convert items of a string into a separate list for each item? `set a [list "1.2 1.3 1.6 1.7 1.8"]` and to have an output like `{1.2}{1.3}{1.6}{1.7}{1.8}`

Comment: Maybe [`set res [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $a]`](https://ideone.com/JEi5zP)?

Comment: It is not working. I tried the same command. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Note that the format you want isn't a list and can't be processed with Tcl list commands.

Comment: @PeterLewerin I just want to store each values in a different list. Currently they are stored in a single list as a string.

Comment: Braces are not a list constructor. {1.2} is no more or less of a list than 1.2. {1.1}{1.2} is just a string (or list with one element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a regular expression to parse the string, and `join` to make something with the result:

```
set a "1.2 1.3 1.6 1.7 1.8"

set b [regexp -all -inline {\S+} $a]
set c "{[join $b "}{"]}"
```

Now, if we *knew* we had a proper list, we'd be able to skip the regular expression stuff, but it is safest to not do that.

---

We could also use `regsub` to do the transformation in this case.

```
set c [regsub -all {\s*(\S+)\s*} $a {{\1}}]
```

However, writing this sort of transformation can get quite a bit more difficult once the transformation required gets more complex.

Answer (score 0):

getting list from a string. We are using whitespace " " as separator of list elements

```
set a [split "1.2 1.3 1.6 1.7 1.8" " "]
```

printing

```
foreach one $a {
    puts -nonewline "{$one}"
}
puts ""
```